# Twitter on Android, missing tweets from Timeline

Tags: twitter

I recently changed my phone, Twitter app was downloaded, now I find that hours of tweets don't appear on my Timeline, if for e.g., I was on 8 hrs ago it wont show tweets since then till about 10 minutes ago, there is no "show more" anymore where it would open up and show tweets that were posted during that period.

Comment: I have not used this app in some time, so I'm working from memory. The Twitter app for Android is lightweight, and only retrieves a known quantity of back tweets. (If I recall correctly, 200). If you follow high-volume users, this will fill up quickly, and ignore everything between. Maybe try a third party Twitter app?

Comment: I just tried this by installing the Twitter app on a device and comparing to my timeline on the web. There is a distinct gap between 1h ago and 11h ago, in the app, so it has skipped presenting 10h of tweets. I estimate the break after about the most current 200, as I said before.